# The set of all real or complex invertible matrices is dense

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I'm trying to show that the set of all invertible matrices $\Omega$ is dense over $F=\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$. Let $A\in\Omega$ and $C\in M_{n\times n}(F)$. Since $\|A-C\|<\frac{1}{||A^{-1}||}$, and $\lambda\neq 0$, $A\in\Omega\implies \lambda A\in\Omega$, we have for $\lambda$ large $\|\lambda A-C\|<\frac{1}{\lambda \|A^{-1}\|}$ is small. So for any open ball $B_{\epsilon}(C)$ centered at $C$, we have $\frac{1}{\epsilon\|A^{-1}\|}<|\lambda|\implies \|\lambda A-C\|<\epsilon$ and $\lambda\in\Omega$.

Does this proof look correct? Also, could you use the same idea to prove that the diagonalizable matrices are dense in $M_{n\times n}(F)$, by just letting $A$ be a diagonal matrix with nonzero eigenvalues?

Comment: What does "F" stand for?

Comment: The field, $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: How do you get $||A-C|| < 1/||A^{-1}||$?  What happens if $A=I$ and $C=-I$?  On a related question, what does the notation $M_{n\times n}(F)$ mean?  A general matrix of size $n\times n$ with coefficents in $F$?

Comment: You're right, it's not true in general, but was an assumption I mistakenly used. And yes, that's what the notation stands for,

Comment: If you have vectors that span a subspace $S$, then for any vector $x \in S$ and any vector $y$ that is orthogonal to $S$, can you show whether or not $x + \epsilon y$ is in $S$ (for $\epsilon$ a small scalar)?  This might be helpful if you progressively modify the columns of your matrix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is all wrong.  What you need to show is that given $C \in M_{n \times n}(F)$ and $\epsilon > 0$ there **exists** $A \in \Omega$ with $\|A - C\| < \epsilon$.  But you are **assuming** that $A \in \Omega$ with $\|A - C\| < 1/\|A\|$.  Then you make the absurd assertion that $\|\lambda A - C \| < \dfrac{1}{\lambda \|A\|}$.  Actually $\|\lambda A - C\| \ge |\lambda| \|A\| - \|C\| \to +\infty$ as $\lambda \to \infty$, not $0$.

Comment: Ah, ok. For some reason when trying to bound $||\lambda A-C||$ I was using $(\lambda A)^{-1}=\lambda A^{-1}$, when it should be $\lambda^{-1}A^{-1}$. So I should pick $\lambda$ small

Comment: No, that won't work either: $\|\lambda A - C\| \to \|C\|$ as $\lambda \to 0$.  What you want to do is take $A = C - \lambda I$ where $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue of $C$.